# How to plot month-day dates on ggplot instead of day of year in r

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I need to create a plot that shows the range between the earliest and the latest date for two groups. There are different years, but I am only interested in the dates defined as month-day (i.e. Feb-04) regardless of years. I am able to do that when defining month-day as Julian days, but I'd like to do it on the month-day format (i.e. Feb-04).

This is the code and output I obtained when working this thing in Julian dates:

```
library(dplyr)

data.1 <-read.csv(text = "
trt,full_date
A,10/06/2020
A,09/19/2017
A,10/28/2014
A,09/02/2016
A,09/19/2017
A,09/26/2017
B,08/24/2020
B,09/24/2020
B,10/16/2018
B,09/16/2018
B,09/15/2016
B,09/09/2018
")

#day of year option
data.2 <- data.1 %>%
  mutate(full_date = as.Date(full_date, format("%m/%d/%Y")),
         full_date.doy = as.numeric(strftime(full_date, format = "%j"))) %>%
  group_by(trt) %>%
  summarise(earliest.doy = min(full_date.doy),
            latest.doy = max(full_date.doy))
                                  
ggplot(data.2) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=trt, xend=trt, y=earliest.doy, yend=latest.doy), color="grey") +
  geom_point( aes(x=trt, y=earliest.doy), color=rgb(0.2,0.7,0.1,0.5), size=3 ) +
  geom_point( aes(x=trt, y=latest.doy), color=rgb(0.7,0.2,0.1,0.5), size=3 ) +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("Day of the year")
```

output:

[image]

What I would like to have is this (dates on the x axis are approximated:
[image]

The first problem I ran into was the calculation of earliest and latest date. For `trt="A"`, the earliest and latest dates are wrong.
[image]

The issue is that the `date_mm.dd` seems to be in character format, and I don't find a way to change to date. That way, the plot is wrong:
[image]

Any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to address this could be to take your `doy` variables and make them into dates in an arbitrary year like 2022. Here, day one will be one day after 2021-12-31, ie Jan 1 2022.

(2022 is not a leap year, so dates originating after Feb 28 in a leap year will be represented ahead by one day. ie Feb 29, when it occurs, is the 60th day of the year, but in most years, like 2022, March 1 is the 60th day, so it would show up there. Depending on the context, you could potentially adjust for that.)

```
data.2 %>%
  mutate(across(contains("doy"), ~as.Date("2021-12-31") + .x))
```

This is a shortcut to ask dplyr to apply the same function to any column whose name contains the string "doy". We could equivalently use:

```
data.2 %>%
  mutate(earliest.doy = as.Date("2021-12-31") + earliest.doy))
  mutate(latest.doy   = as.Date("2021-12-31") + latest.doy))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  trt   earliest.doy latest.doy
  <chr> <date>       <date>    
1 A     2022-09-03   2022-10-28
2 B     2022-08-25   2022-10-16
```

then you could feed that into your existing code:

```
... %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_segment( aes(x=trt, xend=trt, y=earliest.doy, yend=latest.doy), color="grey") +
  geom_point( aes(x=trt, y=earliest.doy), color=rgb(0.2,0.7,0.1,0.5), size=3 ) +
  geom_point( aes(x=trt, y=latest.doy), color=rgb(0.7,0.2,0.1,0.5), size=3 ) +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("Day of the year")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That work perfect. If you have a chance, could you please elaborate on what the ```across``` and ```contains``` do?

Comment: Edited to show a more manual alternative. `across` was added with dplyr 1.0.0 and offers some convenient ways to apply the same calculation to multiple columns.